# Unexpected behaviour when using Google Sheets Macros to create Charts with Count Aggregation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, count, aggregation

I want to create a Macro to create charts based on information from 2 columns (as in the picture below): [image]

The chart I created manually looks like this, where each column from the chart represents how many transactions happened at that exact hour, using the Count Aggregation feature: [image]

The problem I have now is that, despite the Macro clearly stating to use the Count Aggregate function on the first series, it seems to default to Sum Aggregate:

```js
function CreateMaximumsChart() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange("G1").activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  chart = sheet
    .newChart()
    .asColumnChart()
    .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange("H1:H"))
    .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange("G1:G"))
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
    .setNumHeaders(0)
    .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
    .setOption("applyAggregateData", 0)
    .setOption("bubble.stroke", "#000000")
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
    .setOption("isStacked", "false")
    .setOption("title", "Maximums")
    .setOption("series.0.aggregateFunction", "count")
    .setPosition(8, 5, 44, 20)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Which results in this chart being created: [image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? The macro code looks fine on my end, could it be a bug with Google Sheets?

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Ok, I will paste the code instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment out the line that adds the `G1:G` range, since you are not using it for the chart, it will give the same result as the one you have above.

```
function CreateMaximumsChart() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange("G1").activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  chart = sheet
    .newChart()
    .asColumnChart()
    .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange("H1:H"))
//  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange("G1:G")) // Remove this line
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
    .setNumHeaders(0)
    .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
    .setOption("applyAggregateData", 0)
    .setOption("bubble.stroke", "#000000")
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
    .setOption("isStacked", "false")
    .setOption("title", "Maximums")
    .setOption("series.0.aggregateFunction", "count")
    .setPosition(8, 5, 44, 20)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

The issue seems to be that you are adding a range to the chart which you don't need to generate the chart.

Comment: God bless you! I was stumped all day long on this issue! That was the issue!

Comment: Happy to help :)